# TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD not present in InputType Class

Tags: android, sdk

I was working on an EditText where users should put a numeric password.
I was trying to set
          input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER|InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD);

but, it seems that the TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD doesn't exist. I am sure that I'm using android sdk 10 (I'm working on NFC) and on http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html#TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD it seems that the application work. So, why I don't have this constant? Is there another way to do that without the variable?

thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll notice from the link you provided that TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_PASSWORD is in API 11. If you are using an earlier Android API you won't have that type.